# Django: Accessing HttpRequest in Class Based Generic View ListView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'll be implementing a customized class based generic view by sub-classing ListView in my views.py. My question is how will be able to access the request (HttpRequest object) parameter in my sub-class? The HttpRequest object that I am pertaining to is the default request parameter for all functions inside views.py. Example:

```
def search(request):
```

To be clearer, here's what I've tried so far:

**views.py

```
class CustomListView(ListView):
    temp = ""

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.temp = request.GET.get('temp')
        return super(CustomListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CustomListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['temp'] = self.temp
        return context
```

**urls.py

```
url(r'^temp/$, CustomListView.as_view(queryset=Document.objects.all()[:1],template_name="temp.html")),
```

**temp.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>{{ temp }}
{% endblock %}
```

But all I am seeing when I run the server and access /temp/ (temp.html) is 'None'. So meaning, 'temp' is "" or 'temp' was not created at all.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In general, you can use `self.request` in CBV methods that haven't been passed a request. However, you are attempting to set `temp` from the query string (request.GET.get('temp')), so what URL are you using. e.g. http://www.example.com/temp/?temp=whatever ??

Comment: thanks Steven. So just to clarify what you're saying, I can do context['temp'] = self.request on my get_context_data override function? again, thanks!

Comment: You can have `context['temp'] = self.request.GET.get('temp')` in your `get_context_data` method, and then delete your `get` override method entirely.

Comment: Why don't you use `{{ request.GET.temp }}` in your template?

Comment: You should not override `get` and `post` methods unless you're 100% sure of what you're doing. CBVs have a bunch of methods for all kinds of needs, and if all else fails try to modify `dispatch` first.

Comment: Sudip and Steven, thanks a lot for your advises.

Comment: Steven, kindly post your answer so I can tag it as the answer. thanks agian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you can use self.request in CBV methods that haven't been passed a request.

So you can use

```
    context['temp'] = self.request.GET.get('temp')
```

in your `get_context_data` method, and then delete your `get` override method entirely.

Comment: Steven, additional question. Though this is quite different... Can I override the contents of the queryset in the urls.py entry?

Comment: @jaysonpryde: probably worth another question. Not sure I understand what you're asking but you can set a `queryset` attribute on your CustomListView class, or override the `get_queryset` method instead, and get rid of the queryset in urls.py. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview

Comment: he's asking how to use self.request.GE.get('temp') in queryset class parameter. I have the same question